# Windows moving under the Dock panel

Tags: dock

In Ubuntu 22 other windows move under the dock panel. The screen shot shows a terminal that has moved under the Dock. It impedes normal working in this terminal.

[image]

How can this problem be prevented?

Comment: Clarify: what are "other" windows? It is normal that a window can be moved "under" the dock. New windows, however, should open besides the dock, unless perhaps if they are larger than your screen resolution.

Comment: @vanadium, see the clarified question

Comment: Still not clear to me what "other windows" are, and when this situation is triggered. It is difficult for me to try reproduce the issue. But if it is clear to you, it may be clear to others also, just not to me.